# Database is allowing to enter wrong data

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

In the following code I am trying add the row in `gridview` or database only if the date is entered right. It is adding the row in `gridview` or database even though when I enter the wrong date. It is showing error saying that wrong date but still it is adding the wrong data in to database.

```cs
private void btn_AddReservation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int clientId = Convert.ToInt32(txtClientId.Text);
        int roomNumber = Convert.ToInt32(cb_RoomNumber.SelectedValue);
        DateTime dateIn = dtPDateIn.Value;
        DateTime dateOut = dtPDateOut.Value;

        if(DateTime.Compare(dateIn.Date,DateTime.Now.Date) < 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Date In must be = or >  Today Date","Invalid Date In",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else if(DateTime.Compare(dateOut.Date,dateIn.Date) < 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Date Out must be = or >  Today Date", "Invalid Date Out", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Reservation Not Added ", "Add Reservation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        if (reservation.addReservation(roomNumber, clientId, dateIn, dateOut))
        {
            dGvReservations.DataSource = reservation.getAllReservations();
           
            room.setRoomFree(roomNumber, "No");
            MessageBox.Show("New Reservation Added ", "Add Reservation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }       
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Add Reservation Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Learn to debug. After any one of your messageboxes is displayed, what happens in your code?

Comment: When you have a wrong date you just print that you have a wrong date. You don't do anything else and you do not stop it from being added.

Comment: Your code has a couple of issues... 1) You will always show a messagebox in the else case of the date comparation. Is this what you want?? 2) Your if(...addReservation...) does an insert (I think. Is not clear enough in your example) and this is the issue in my opinion

Comment: I am just learning. Please help me what to do

Comment: and In addReservation I wrote this Code
            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            {
                con.closeConnection();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                con.closeConnection();
                return false;
            }

Comment: Look at the answer I posted. It might help you to understand what your issue is :)

Answer (score 0):

**Here a working solution:**

1. Check if the dates are correct
2. In the else case (dates are correct) do your insert as shown below

```
private void btn_AddReservation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            int clientId = Convert.ToInt32(txtClientId.Text);
            int roomNumber = Convert.ToInt32(cb_RoomNumber.SelectedValue);
            DateTime dateIn = dtPDateIn.Value;
            DateTime dateOut = dtPDateOut.Value;


            if (DateTime.Compare(dateIn.Date, DateTime.Now.Date) < 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The Date In must be = or >  Today Date", "Invalid Date In", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
            else if (DateTime.Compare(dateOut.Date, dateIn.Date) < 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The Date Out must be = or >  Today Date", "Invalid Date Out", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
            else
            {
                // Date is correct, you insert it in db.

                bool success = reservation.addReservation(roomNumber, clientId, dateIn, dateOut);
                if (success)
                {
                    dGvReservations.DataSource = reservation.getAllReservations();

                    room.setRoomFree(roomNumber, "No");
                    MessageBox.Show("New Reservation Added ", "Add Reservation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error inserting ", "There was an error inserting the new reservation in the database", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Add Reservation Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Perhaps _describe_ the changes you made?

Comment: And you actually don't need the flag neither the empty else, you can refractor to put the content of the `if(shouldInsertInDb)` in the else.

Comment: @PhilippeB. Yes of corse. You are right. Next time I will take my time hahah. I accepted your edit, Thanks